# How to make a life meter using a while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

My code fails to return the message I have inputted when reaching the maximum amount of fails. This is a form of a 'life meter.' Here is the code:

```
import random

lives = 3

coin = (
    'heads',
    'tails'
    )

ask = input('Are you ready?')

if ask == 'yes':
    print('Good')
else:
    print('No is not an option')

coin_flip = random.randint(0,1)

choice = input('Heads or tails?')

print('It was', coin[coin_flip])

if choice != coin_flip:
    lives = lives-1

while lives >0 :
    coin_flip = random.randint(0,1)
    choice = input('Heads or tails?')
    print('It was', coin[coin_flip])

    if choice != coin_flip:
        lives = lives-1

    if lives <1 :
        print('You are out')
```

I have assigned the original lives to the number 3, and everytime I get it wrong, it should take a life off. I think it may be due to the fact that 'coin_flip' is not assigned as a paticular string, just the random call it gets. If I am right about that, how can I make it catch the inputted string, and put it against the random answer each time?

EDIT:
My indentation was wrong, which is why I was not recieving the message. Now, I need to understand why it cannot catch 'heads or tails' when in the random output.

Comment: your second `if choice != coin_flip:` needs to be indented...and the following line

Comment: Shouldn't `if choice != coin_flip` be `if choice != coin[coin_flip]`?

Comment: What is your input to `choice`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can post an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement which checks the actual coin flip to the guess must be indented and nested within the while loop:

```
while lives >0 :
   coin_flip = random.randint(0,1)
   choice = input('Heads or tails?')
   print('It was', coin[coin_flip])
   if choice != coin[coin_flip]:
      lives = lives-1
```

In addition your check will always be wrong because you compare the choice variable to the random integer and not the coin face which it represents. As you have done before in the print statement, simply select the item from tuple based on it's position.

Additionally, as you learn more basic python you will be able to handle user error such as capitalized strings, trailing spaces, incorrect characters etc..

**I.E. Note that**  -       heads != Heads

Comment: Yes, I do know how to accept multiple answers and I understand that 'heads != Heads. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is messed up

You need to indent the following, so it is inside the while loop. If you do not do this, the while loop will never end and this code will never be ran

```
if choice != coin_flip:
    lives = lives-1

if lives <1 :
    print('You are out')
```

Comment: Thanks, that partly answers my question. See EDIT for more details.

Comment: There are other severe issues with this post. The correct response is to close it down, not enable the OP by answering.

Comment: Also, your indentation is all messed up too, much worse than OP's since his did not cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are right in a sense; there are several things wrong with this program. However, my indentation is not messed up as I only provided a snippet of the code which has no need to be indented.

Comment: @Splinxyy. No, the snippet you provided is going to raise an error in any context. Python is space sensitive.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just realised my fatal mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.